# PHP - How to get images from directory, separate them into pages

Tags: php, jquery, html, image, directory

I'm trying to get images from a folder and show them in a single page.

```
<ul>
<?php
foreach(glob('images/*.*') as $singleImg){
    echo '<li><img src="'.$singleImg.'" /></li>';
}
?>
</ul>
```

but there are hundreds of them.

Is there a way to show them in groups using PHP, JQuery or just Java?

I have 100, and I want to show 20, then click a link/button/scroll to show 20 more. Instead of showing them all at the same time?

Comment: One word: pagination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, there are multiple ways of doing it. You could use an Ajax call to get the next/previous 20 images, or keep track of which set of images you are on with a hidden field and post that to the server when the next/previous button is clicked.

The thing you want to AVOID is loading all of them at one time.